# Python REGEX returns additional string data than regex101 Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have an [EXAMPLE HERE](https://www.regex101.com/r/eBv963/1) of some regular expressions that find latitude which seems to work great within the example. I transfer this over to python and print line with match and then match string using

```
line = "position:      0.00ft Northing:    728398.54  ft    Latitude:         31     38    40.268 N"
Lat = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}.*\s\d{1,2}.*\s\d{1,2}.*N",line.translate(None, '\x00'))
if len(Lat) > 0:
  print(line)
  latitude = Lat[0]
  print(latitude)
# 728398.54  ft    Latitude:         31     38    40.268 N
```

Where have I gone wrong in my regex expression?

I wish to return: "31 38 40.268 N"

Comment: Please explain why the results that you see are wrong.

Comment: The line is the second block of output and the match is the first block of output. The results as you can see within the example is that Im looking for the Latitude value which would be "31 38 40.268 N"  @DYZ

Comment: At regex101, you are using lazy dot matching patterns, `.*?`. Here, you show greedy dot, `.*`. The data seems different from what you have in Python from the one you shared at regex101.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this does not affect the outcome

Comment: It depends on the data you have.

Comment: Why do you need `.translate(None, '\x00')` at all?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wouldn't say that is the point the point is that I have made a fundamental error in python that returns a separate value

Comment: @DYZ because there is null bytes littered throughout my text, and what version of python are you running could this be my issue? I am returning exactly what I have put here

Comment: Your text on regex101 contains line breaks.

Comment: @DYZ I was looking for the latitude value which is "31 38 40.268 N" nothing else

Comment: @melpomene is that a rhetorical statement or a clue towards a solution

Comment: @TylerCowan https://www.regex101.com/r/eBv963/2 It's why you're getting different results: The input strings are different.

Comment: @melpomene I see. thanks for that

Answer (score -1):

What about this regex instead: [`Latitude:\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/eBv963/3), degrees in group 1, minutes in group 2 and seconds in group 3

```
import re
line = "position:      0.00ft Northing:    728398.54  ft    Latitude:         31     38    40.268 N"
result = re.search(r"Latitude:\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)", line)
formatted = result.group(1) + " " + result.group(2) + " " + result.group(3) + " N"
print(formatted)
```

Comment: Although that is an interesting solution, The word Latitude may not exist at all or be misspelled so it would be preferential to match a pattern vs using latitude as a marker

Comment: Just remove it, it will still work if the format is only used for the latitude.

Comment: Unfortunately no also the group method does not work for me